# Is there a way to use loose modules when using es2015 preset in babel 6?

Tags: babeljs

I tried to use following babelrcs:

```json
{
  "presets": [
     ["es2015", { "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": { "loose": true } }]
  ]
}
```

fails with "Invalid options type for foreign"

```json
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

ignores the "loose" option

```json
{
  "plugins": [
     ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

does not use the preset

Comment: There is a dedicated package for that purpose, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37425906/1480391

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating a preset [es2015-mod](https://github.com/orlin/babel-preset-es2015-mod) for this same purpose - an exact copy of Babel's `es2015` with loose modules enabled.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought of too, only with -amd. the issue is that it's more work then previously in babel 5

Comment: @zowers I got a nice pull request on the that repo and am now making use of a `modify-babel-preset` module which allows for overriding configuration without explicit list of all the es2015 plugins / hardly any dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

By enabling `es2015`, you are asking for non-loose-mode modules. If you want loose module modes in Babel v6 (at least at the moment), you would need to explicitly list the plugins you wish to use by listing everything that is part of `es2015`.

Comment: by enabling es2015 I'm only following easiest way to transpile es2015-code into es3 code, which is strange.

Comment: I would rather expect default preset to be called es3 or es5

Comment: babel 5 had one option which switched the behavior, now I am expected to list several who-knows-which plugins, include them all to the list of my devDependencies

Comment: It will get easier. Babel 6 has only been out for a day, the kinks are still being worked out. If you need to just get work done, stick with v5 for now.

Answer (score 1):

[`babel-preset-es2015-loose` package has been deprecated](https://github.com/bkonkle/babel-preset-es2015-loose). With `babel-preset-es2015` v6.13.0+, you can now configure your `.babelrc` like so:

`{ presets: [ ["es2015", {"loose": true}] ] }`

Comment: For me it was an old `babel-core` package

Answer (score 1):

For me it was an old `babel-core` version. You need at least `6.13+`

Answer (score 0):

## NEW: Using es2015-loose preset

[es2015-loose](https://github.com/bkonkle/babel-preset-es2015-loose) is a preset that uses modify-babel-preset to modify [es2015](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-es2015) preset and enable [loose mode](https://developit.github.io/babel-legacy-docs//docs/advanced/loose/) where available.

Use it like that:

```json
{
  "presets": ["es2015-loose"]
}
```

Make sure to install both [es2015](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-es2015) and [es2015-loose](https://github.com/bkonkle/babel-preset-es2015-loose) packages:

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015-loose babel-preset-es2015
```

---

PS: There are other loose presets for example if you target node versions >= 4 you can use [es2015-node4-loose](https://github.com/yvele/babel-preset-es2015-node4-loose) preset.